# How to bind an IP Address to my Azure Web Role so that the Web APIs can be accessed globally by a remote computer?

Tags: c#, iis, azure, iis-express, azure-web-roles

The Web Role of my Azure application has Web APIs which i want to access through a remote computer. Normally it should work if I just add the bindings to my website in applicationhost.config file of iis express. But for Windows Azure project the emulator is attaching the web role to iis express and giving a default url of "127.255.0.0:82".

Now how can i bind an ip address to my web role? or how can i access my APIs from a remote computer?

Comment: Do I get you right, that you want to access the Web API on your WebRole via a different Port than :80?

Comment: I want to access my web role from a remote computer using my ip address. Any idea?

Comment: It depends on what kind of API you want to access and how. If you're providing a WebService in your WebRole that publishes its API on the standard http port, there's nothing to do but to call the API since the LoadBalancer will take care of how the request is passed to the RoleInstance. If you want to use any other port than :80 you need to define a new endpoint in your ServiceDefinition.csdef file. Choose TCP/UDP protocol whatever fits your needs. - If you could provide more information about what API you want to call, that'd be helpful.

Comment: Firstly i want to clarify that "127.255.0.0:82" is not my ip address, its just default local address provided by emulator i think. And i cant use it to open the website from some other computer. And i just want to open my website hosted in the web role from some other computer using my actual ip address.

Comment: Okay, this means you want to access your local dev fabric from a different computer, right?

Comment: yep - this time you get an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Development Fabric uses loopback addresses to host Windows Azure Roles, so there is no default way to access those service from a remote computer.

Have a look here: http://blog.sacaluta.com/2012/03/windows-azure-dev-fabric-access-it.html
Rodrigo De Castro proposes a port mapping to make web roles hosted in the dev fabric accessible for remote computers.

I haven't tried it myself yet, but it sounds promising.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! It works!! The below software forwards the port requess from your ip address to the local 127.255.0.0:82. 

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjs-passport/

Answer (score 0):

I am using the [An easier way to access the Windows Azure local development fabric from another computer](http://blog.sacaluta.com/2012/03/windows-azure-dev-fabric-access-it.html). with [RINETD](http://www.boutell.com/rinetd/) and [serviceex](http://serviceex.com/). Very nice mix of tools and approach.

I was also successfully able to Edit bindings as a [temporary workaround](http://renouncedthoughts.wordpress.com/2013/12/31/add-bindings-to-your-azure-role-in-azure-compute-emulator/) from my IIS (not IIS Express). [*Below image with original resolution*](http://renouncedthoughts.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/untitled_clipping_123113_083620_pm.jpg).

[image]